# Can you attack while Gliding?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Say I have a hunter with the [*Glide*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/glide) spell, and I use it to jump off a high cliff overlooking an orc encampment.

Assuming the cliff is high enough to give me at least a couple rounds before reaching the ground, can I shoot at the orcs beneath me as I descend? Would there be any penalties associated with this, such as those associated with the [*Levitate*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/levitate) spell? Could I make a full attack, and if so would I still be able to move horizontally while falling as described in the spell?

Similarly, if I were to jump off a cliff into a flock of harpies, could I make melee attacks against them? (And could I full attack?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can attack, melee or missile, full or standard, while using the glide spell.  If you use it to move, that's your move action for the round so you could still attack but not full attack.  The penalties described in Levitate are unique to levitate, there is no reason for them to apply here.